# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '21:5:20' could not be parsed at index 3

Tags: java, localtime, zoneddatetime, localdatetime

I am currently getting this error and I really don't know why

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '21:5:20' could not be parsed at index 3
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
        at java.time.LocalTime.parse(LocalTime.java:441)
...
```

This is the method I use for parsing.

```
public static ZonedDateTime parse(String fecha, String pattern) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME;
    LocalTime date = LocalTime.parse(fecha, formatter);

    return ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), date), ZoneId.systemDefault());
  }
```

I need to return a `ZonedDateTime` and therefore I'm doing what I'm doing.
The error says it seems to read the correct time from the file `21:5:20`, which looks valid, but for some reason it fails to parse it.

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. Similar questions to this were referring to Dates, intead of Time.

I know this seems like a trivial problem, but I would honestly appreciate some help from the Java experts out here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ensure that all time elements within the time string contains 2 digits (like the missing leading 0 in the minutes).

Comment: @DevilsHnd i cannot change the input, duh. The data is read from somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use the format `"H:m:s"`.

**Detail:**

The hour, minute, and second in `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME` are in the format, `HH:mm:ss` whereas your time string does not have minutes in two digits. The format, `"H:m:s"` caters to time units in both, single and double-digit.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(parse("21:5:20", "H:m:s"));
    }

    public static ZonedDateTime parse(String fecha, String pattern) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(fecha, formatter);

        return ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), time), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }

}
```

**Output in my timezone:**

```
2021-06-27T21:05:20+01:00[Europe/London]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/rx8kgu)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

The time is formatted incorrectly for `ISO_LOCAL_TIME`.
The hours, minutes and seconds have a fixed width of 2 digits each.
They should be left-padded with zeros to ensure two digits.
A parseable time would be: `21:05:20`

If you can't change the input format, you can create your own DateTimeFormatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 1, 2, SignStyle.NEVER)
        .optionalStart()
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
        .toFormatter();

LocalTime date = LocalTime.parse("21:5:20", formatter);

System.out.println(date);
```

Prints:

> `21:05:20`

Comment: Well I can't change the input, is there something I can do to be able to parse this time-format?

Comment: what do you mean with handle? btw I thought of just splitting the string at `:` inside the method itself, and just doing ` LocalTime date = LocalTime.of(Integer.parseInt(s[0]), Integer.parseInt(s[1]), Integer.parseInt(s[2]));`. Now unlocked a whole new world of errors.